# Is it possible to copy files between 2 network drives directly?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer

My understanding is, if I copy one or more files between two network drives (remote PCs), the transfer will be routed via my local PC. So if I were to then shutdown my PC before the copy completes, the operation is cancelled or possibly incomplete/corrupted.

Is there a way to perform a copy where it tells either the source or destination to initiate the file operation remotely? And could this copy be integrated into windows file explorer in a user friendly manner?

Comment: Limit yourself to a single question here. The answer is "it depends", and it depends on a lot of factors. First, if this is a business environment, please work with your local IT department as they are responsible for this sort of thing for you. Second, in order to copy without requiring your computer to be part of the process you will need to initiate the copy from either of the network drives themselves, and unless you're using some 3rd party utility, you won't get a user friendly indicator in the File Explorer UI on your computer of the transfer status.

Comment: This is mostly an academic exercise. I had to copy some files from my old NAS to my new one (home environment, but it could apply to enterprise in some scenarios) and was wondering if there was an efficient way to do it without having to ssh in (or remote desktop or something).

I guess to phrase the question differently: "Can my standard windows file explorer experience be extended so it's smart enough to recognise and optimise a file transfer when neither the source or destination is local?"

Comment: File Explorer doesn't do that. Any system that does do that would need to be able to run SSH or remote sessions of some sort, or a client server setup, in order to get what you want. So, any solution would be a pretty skin on top of the things you already list.